# middleware- bind to middlewares

Tags: node.js, express

I'm new to express.  Trying to set up a middleware to build a fields blacklist depending on the user's role so admin fields aren't visible to regular visitors.

I can't seem to get things working though.  Is it possible to have more than 1 middleware in the `app.param()` method?

```
 'use strict';

/**
 * Module dependencies.
 */
var businessPolicy = require('../policies/businesses.server.policy'),
    business = require('../controllers/businesses.server.controller');

//routes

module.exports = function (app) {
  // Business collection routes
  app.route('/api/businesses/search/:businessField/:value').all(businessPolicy.isAllowed)
    .get(business.read);


  app.route('/api/businesses').all(businessPolicy.isAllowed)
    .get(business.list)
    .post(business.create);

  // Single business routes
  app.route('/api/businesses/:businessId').all(businessPolicy.isAllowed)
    .get(business.read)
    .put(business.update)
    .delete(business.delete);

  // Finish by binding the business middleware
  app.param('businessId', business.blacklistFields, business.businessByID);

};



//controller
exports.blacklistFields = function(req, res, next){

  //create a blacklist of fields based on role here
  next();
}
exports.businessByID = function (req, res, next, id) {

  if (!mongoose.Types.ObjectId.isValid(id)) {
    return res.status(400).send({
      message: 'Business is invalid'
    });
  }

  Business.findById(id).populate('user', 'displayName').select(/*blacklist fields here*/ ).exec(function (err, business) {
    if (err) {
      return next(err);
    } else if (!business) {
      return res.status(404).send({
        message: 'No businesses with that identifier has been found'
      });
    }
    req.business = business;
    next();
  });
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I can't seem to get things working though. Is it possible to have more than 1 middleware in the app.param() method?

No.

[Docs](http://expressjs.com/en/api.html#app.param) say only one callback is received (and not multiple notation like for eg. `.delete()`).

You can load yours `blacklistFields` in `businessByID()` or another `app.param('user', ...)` for example where depending on user roles `blacklistFields` is filled.

You can setup this middleware you need in another place like: `app.route('/api/*').all(fillBlacklistFields)`

Note that:

> Middleware functions are executed sequentially, therefore the order of middleware inclusion is important.